# How to get banshee music name through dbus?

Tags: d-bus, banshee

```
qdbus org.bansheeproject.Banshee /org/bansheeproject/Banshee/PlayerEngine
```

how to get the value of this property?

```
property read QVariantMap org.bansheeproject.Banshee.PlayerEngine.CurrentTrack
```

Answer (score 0):

foud it at [here](http://banshee-media-player.2283330.n4.nabble.com/Dbus-and-properties-tp3325623p3325964.html)

we need to actually use gdbus:

```
gdbus call -e -d org.bansheeproject.Banshee \
  -o /org/bansheeproject/Banshee/PlayerEngine \
  -m org.bansheeproject.Banshee.PlayerEngine.GetCurrentTrack
```